# 90s(?) movie or TV film, business man from modern times is a warrior of a forgotten line in a fantasy world. He wields a collapsible spear or staff

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Ok this is a huge shot in the dark. I remember seeing a live action movie on TV (probably late 90s) and some vivid scenes were it was a man from modern times with a collapsible spear (or staff) and he was stuck in a fantasy world with magical creatures and he was a warrior of some forgotten line.

The scene I remember most was near the end when the villain from the fantasy world invaded our modern world and the business man took up his spear/staff thingy again to defeat him, and some of his friends from the fantasy world also came to help. There might have been a bit with them flying on a cloud too?

Comment: Hey there! That's some good info already, and I know you said it was vague, but please still take a look at [this handy guide on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in. Every detail, however minor it may seem, counts. Cheers :)

Comment: Accept for the businessman in modern times bit your description (extendable staff, flying on clouds) sounds like [Monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_(TV_series)), isn't of course, what you've given us is a bit vague, naturally (or you wouldn't need help finding it), any other details though?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gor_(film) ?

Comment: @bishop : I wouldn't think so, OP seems clear that the action takes place on Earth, secondly, OMG! they actually turned that piece of misogynistic tat into a film! I'm male & despite that can scarcely read any of it without cringing, so it must be pretty bad, putting that aside the writing's fairly bad as well.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a miniseries called [The Monkey King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_King_(miniseries)), AKA The Lost Empire.

Looks like you can see the whole thing on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k55HWVYbRE). There's at least one cloud flying scene at [29 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k55HWVYbRE&t=1760s). And a scene of the staff expanding at [about 21 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k55HWVYbRE&t=1286s).

The timeline is a little off - you mentioned late 90s and this was from 2001. I don't recall the villain invading the modern world, exactly, but the series does end in modern times.